# EXIF-JS data is getting undefined outside of the method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, exif-js

I am developing a web application using Angular 8. I just want to access the exif data of an input image outside the getData method by assigning the obtained data to a global variable. If i tried to access the global variable after executing function it is showing undefined.
here is the function for extracting the exif data:

```
photodata: any; // global variable
getPhotodata(file) {
    EXIF.getData(file, function() {
      const data = EXIF.getAllTags(this);
      console.log(data); // working
      console.log(data.Make); // working
      console.log(data.Model); // working
      console.log(data.DateTimeOriginal); // working
      this.photodata = data;
      console.log(this.photodata) // working
  });
  }
  console.log(this.photodata) // here it is showing undefined
```

i have tried to return the data. But it also does not worked

```
getPhotodata(file) {
    EXIF.getData(file, function() {
      const data = EXIF.getAllTags(this);
      console.log(data); // working
      console.log(data.Make); // working
      console.log(data.Model); // working
      console.log(data.DateTimeOriginal); // working
      return data;
  });
  }
console.log(getPhotodata(file)) // undefined
```

Comment: Your issue is time, not inside/outside the function. Check *when* each `console.log()` is executed. You need to learn a bit about async programming.

Comment: yeah it worked using async and await. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I'm aware you probably solved this by now, but in case async programming got you curious, you might enjoy my library [exifr](https://github.com/MikeKovarik/exifr). I've written it because exif-js is effectively dead now (not maintained for over 2 years), it's pretty ineffective. Exifr is built around promises and async/await syntax, so you can do this:

```
async function getExif() {
  let output = await exifr.parse(file)
  console.log(data.Make)
  console.log(data.Model)
}
```

You can also try out the library's [playground](http://mutiny.cz/exifr/) and experiment with images and their output, or check out the [repository and docs](https://github.com/MikeKovarik/exifr).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `console.log(output.Make)` instead of data?